# Gomchen Lam Rim Text Request

Tags: reference-request, texts, tibetan-buddhism

I've recently been following along on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9H7YI4qX7BI) video series on the Gomchen Lam Rim and would very much like to find a copy of the root text so I can follow along better and read ahead, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I would especially like to find a free pdf somewhere, but I'm also okay with proprietary books.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been trying to locate the text also. [This link](https://www.jangchuplamrim.org/2014/12/12/todays-lamrim-quote-12-december-2014/) mentions,

*The Pearl Garland: An Anthology of Lamrims*
translated from the Tibetan under Venerable Dagpo Rinpoche’s guidance by Rosemary Patton, Editions Guepele (France), 2012.